# При создании проекта в структуре имеются ошибки

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-sdk, gradle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал LoginActivity и уже сразу имеются проблемы.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Мой gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alex.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: У вас такая проблема наблюдается только с данным типом Activity или и в других проектах?

Comment: @Valeriy, в других проектах тоже самое.

Comment: Сильно похоже на то что у вас не настроен %PATH% https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml, Второе: я так понимаю вы хотите писать под Android и используете для этого Intellij. Думаю вам стоит начать с AndroidStudio, в принципе тоже самое но более заточено под работу с Android-sdk, соответственно и легче начать.

Comment: тут о настройке  PATH более понятно написано: http://java-course.ru/begin/install-jdk/

Answer (score 0):

У вас не определён репозиторий зависимостей. Попробуйте добавить что-то типа:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

или

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Больше похоже что у него не настроенная переменная окружения %PATH% или проблемы с Gradle plugin, где нужно обновить Gradle и желательно полностью установить "SDK platform package" последней версии.

Comment: У меня есть такой код в build.gradle
@Valeriy, к переменной Path я добавлял путь gradle к папке bin. Только что пробовал обновлять Gradle, тоже самое(